# How to send HttpwebRequest request payload

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, payload

I have a webRequest to create. So I am using (httpwebrequest)webrequest.Create("/get").
I need to send some payload/request body to this request.
But stream writer only seems to work with POST request.
How do I achieve that?

Comment: What HTTP method/verb are you using? A GET method/verb doesn't (or at least shouldn't) allow content. Rather than describing your code, can you [edit] your post with an [mre]?

Comment: Why are you using such an outdated API for HTTP communication? Can you upgrade to HttpClient?

Answer (score 0):

You should not attempt to use a get request to post data to a server. Instead, you should use a post request to accomplish this. It is highly recommended that you do not use a `webrequest` and instead use `HttpClient` but if for some reason you absolutely must use `webrequest` like if you're working with legacy code this is the basic method of accomplishing this:

```
try
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.server.example/api/example");
    request.Method = "POST";
    byte[] package = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("package string example");
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = package.Length;
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(package, 0, package.Length);
    dataStream.Close();
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    using (dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        //do something with the data retrieved from the server
    }
    response.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
//example catch
}
```

Comment: the `try catch` block may not be needed necessarily as the using statement will compile into a `try finally` block, but it will allow you to catch exceptions before the using statement.